# Error "no buffer space available" using CanSocket (java) on BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: java, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I have a problem with using CanSocket on a BeagleBoneBlack. I tried to figured it out by myself using google 
and beagle bone documentation but nothing helps me. 
I am using the BeagleBoneBlack as a translator that translates messages between a can device and my pc. The following 
figure shows my setup:

**|CAN device|<--------->|BeagleBoneBlack|<--------->|my PC|**

The translator software on the BeagleBoneBlack is written in java using entropia/libsocket-can-java from github
(see https://github.com/entropia/libsocket-can-java).
Sometimes I get the error "no buffer space available" on the BeagleBoneBlack in CanSocket "write"-method even when
I set the parameter "txqueuelen" to 1000 or even higher (for example 100000 or 1000000). I used the command "sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000" for that. I am wondering about that
because the bus load in this cases is just 14% (I monitored it with CANalyzer).

I would be very grateful for help as it is very important for me to find a solution.
Below some information you might need.

CAN-Bus:
Baudrate = 500 kBit/s

BeagleBoneBlack:
OS = Debian Linux

my PC:
OS = Windows 10 x64

**EDIT: 10th September 2018, 09:40**
CAN-Interface:
CAN-Transceiver TJA1040

Since I do not know exactly what information I should give here, I ask you just to ask and I will try to obtain them.

Comment: Could you please expand what CAN interface hardware you are using with the BBB? It doesn't come with a transceiver itself. Are you able to communicate with your CAN device in any other way from the BBB?

Comment: Hello @TBR, thanks for your reply. I edited my question. I use the CAN-Transceiver TJA1040 with my BBB. I am not able to communicate with my CAN device in any other way from the BBB (e.g. USB, etc.). Cause its a simple CAN device with no other interfaces. The CAN communication works at the beginning but after some minutes I get the error "no buffer space available" and the communication breaks off. If you can give me advice in which direction to look I would be very grateful. Regards

Comment: I still have no clue how to fix this… Is there anybody who can help me?